# Cannot access firebase storage rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am getting an error of:
Error loading rules: Requests from IP address **.**.**.** are blocked.
When trying to access security rules throguh the console.
I tried from other computers and networks and it persists.

Comment: Did you contact firebase support about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. You live in a place where Firebase can't serve traffic (US has sanctions against T5+ countries, for instance)
2. You have added API key restrictions that restrict what IPs you can access our APIs from (check in https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials for your keys and see if they have IP restrictions)

You may be able to use the Firebase CLI to upload rules to your default bucket:

```
firebase init storage
open storage.rules             # edit with your favorite editor
firebase deploy --only storage
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
1. I'm from israel, so I don't believe so.
2. The only key that is restricted is the server key used by my node server, I added my office IP just in case but it didn't change anything.
The rest of the keys are not restricted.

Comment: BTW, it once worked OK, but for some time now doesn't.